# To post at twitter, do I need omniauth gem too (along with twitter gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I am using devise and looking to post to twitter using "twitter" gem but I am little confused, do I also need omniauth gem too ? Do I need to configure omniauth with devise (I am using it for users) first before I can use "twitter" gem so users can post tweets

EDIT - btw, it is the users which will be sending tweets to their respective tweeter accounts

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you don't need Omniauth gem, only twitter is enough

This is what I did

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'twitter'
```

create your app
[from this url](https://dev.twitter.com/apps), and make sure you give your app the **POST**, permission

**config/initializers/twitter.rb**

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = ""
  config.consumer_secret = ""
  config.oauth_token = ""
  config.oauth_token_secret = ""
end
```

then call it as

```
Twitter.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
```

on a side note, if you have any url to be shorten use [bitly](https://github.com/philnash/bitly)

go to bitly and grab your [access token](https://bitly.com/a/oauth_apps)

Gem file

gem 'bitly'

and call it as

```
bitly = Bitly.new("key", "key")
shorten_url = bitly.shorten("http://skylinelive.com")
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get upto putting the keys, but where should I use "Twitter.update" function and how ? also I am not sure I was clear or not, but it is the users which will be posting to their tweeter account through the app

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need Omniauth to allow your users to post tweets. Omniauth is for authentication only -- that means logging into your website and creating user accounts.

I could direct you better to what you need if you included info as to how the posting should work on your website. If all you want is to let them tweet a link to the current page, you need to include the code for the [Tweet Button](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) into the desired page.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get upto putting the keys, but where should I use "Twitter.update" function and how ? also I am not sure I was clear or not, but it is the users which will be posting to their tweeter account through the app

Comment: now I am able to make the tweets! but still how to make each user post in their accounts (right now the tweets are being sent to only one account whose oauth_token I have filled in /initializers/twitter.rb file)